# SSMS Joins and COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a database which records all the jobs that we complete for the various departments in the business.

Table 1 is Department – this stores the name of the department alongside it's ID

Table 2 is Section – this stores the name of section alongside it's ID (one department could have several sections)

Table 3 is User – name of the person who completed the task, alongside the department and section id that the task was for)

Table 4 is date of completion – this contains the name of the person who completed the task and the date it was submitted to the system

Big boss wants me to provide a report that will detail how many jobs each department and section have submitted within a certain time frame.

So far I have got this:

```
SELECT  Dept.DepartmenttId,
Name.SectionId,
count (Name.DepartmentId)  
FROM    Name  
LEFT join Job on Name.UserId = Job.UserId  
WHERE Job.DateSubmitted > '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000' and Job.DateSubmitted <'2017-09-30 23:59:59.000'  
Group by Name.DepartmentId, Name.SectionId
```

That gives me results like:

```
BOB      2    3  
STEVE    1    2
```

where I am getting the name of person alongside the department ID and section ID.

What I want is:

```
Bob    IT    Development
```

so I can see the name of the department and section rather than the IDs.

I've been playing around with joins, but everything I try breaks the count part. Is there a way to get the count and the names within one query? Have I gone wrong in the way I've structured what I have so far?

Current tables:

DEPARTMENT

```
DepartmentId :: DepartmentName  
1 :: IT  
2 :: Marketing  
3 :: Finance
```

SECTION

```
SectionId :: SectionName    
1 :: Development  
2 :: Helpdesk  
3 :: Architecture  
4 :: Procurement
```

NAME

```
Name :: JobId :: DepartmentId :: SectionId   
Bob :: J1234 :: 1 :: 2  
Steve :: J1235 :: 3 :: 4
```

JOB

```
JOBId :: DateSubmitted  
J1234 :: 02/09/2017  
J1235 :: 04/09/2017
```

Comment: Hard to answer this without seeing table structure and/or sample data.  I don't even know which other columns you would need to bring in for the department etc.

Comment: You do not need COUNT() function

Comment: Is there a different way to get the count info then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following SQL Select

```
SELECT  
    Name.Name, DepartmentName, SectionName
FROM Name 
INNER JOIN Job on Name.JobId = Job.JobId
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT on Name.DepartmentID = DEPARTMENT.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN Section on Name.SectionID = Section.SectionID
WHERE 
    Job.DateSubmitted between '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000' and '2017-09-30 23:59:59.000'
```

For displaying job count, you can use following SQL query

```
SELECT  
    DepartmentName, SectionName, Count(*) as JobCount
FROM Job 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT on Name.DepartmentID = DEPARTMENT.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN Section on Name.SectionID = Section.SectionID
WHERE 
    Job.DateSubmitted between '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000' and '2017-09-30 23:59:59.000'
Group By
    DepartmentName, SectionName
```

Comment: That seems to be giving me the data I need - in the sense that it is a list of all the names, along with department/section for a set period. How then could I transform that data so instead it would show the number of jobs per department and section?

Comment: I modified the answer and added a second query

Comment: That query isn't working for me. I think the problem is that the inner join is based on the Name table, but the name table doesn't appear anywhere in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query provided by Eralper, I think I've got it:

```
SELECT DepartmentName, SectionName, Count(*) as JobCount  
FROM Name  
INNER JOIN Department on Name.DepartmentId = Department.DepartmentId  
INNER JOIN Section on Name.SectionId = Section.SectionId  
INNER JOIN Job on Name.JobId = Job.JobId  
WHERE Job.DateSubmitted between '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000' and '2017-09-20 23:59:59.000'  
GROUP BY DepartmentName, SectionName
```